# Cant pass "status" as HttpParameter to Spring Boot MVC Application

Tags: spring, http, model-view-controller, spring-boot, status

I am running a Spring boot MVC application, when i pass "status" as one of the http Parameter (http://localhost:8080/greeting?status=Soemthing), it just fails with following error.

> Field error in object 'modelAndView' on field 'status': rejected value [Soemthing]; codes [typeMismatch.modelAndView.status,typeMismatch.status,typeMismatch.org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [modelAndView.status,status]; arguments []; default message [status]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.http.HttpStatus] for property 'status'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.http.HttpStatus] for value 'Soemthing'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.Soemthing]

How to reporoduce it
Download Spring official mvc demo project from here
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content

Change Greetign Controller as following

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public ModelAndView greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model, ModelAndView mv) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    mv.setViewName("greeting");
    return mv;
}
```

I Just added a new parameter ModelAndView, also changed return type as ModelAndview instead of String.

Run the project and hit url http://localhost:8080/greeting?status=Soemthing , it doesnt work.

Have spent lot of time debugging it, cant find anything.

Complete Stacktrace is here

> org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'modelAndView' on field 'status': rejected value [Something]; codes [typeMismatch.modelAndView.status,typeMismatch.status,typeMismatch.org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [modelAndView.status,status]; arguments []; default message [status]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus' for property 'status'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.http.HttpStatus] for value 'Something'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.Something]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Why are you passing 'status' if the parameter should be 'name' ? Also, judging by the error, 'Soemthing' is not a valid value for HttpStatus - you should try one which is found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html

Comment: in example, it is named as "name". Why do you use like 'status'?

Comment: name http param already exists in this example, i tried to make mimimum changes in official example code of Spring boot. "name" parameter is defined but its not required to pass it as it has its own default value. Main question is when i am passing a paramater "status" why its trying to convert it as HttpStatus enum rather then keeping it normal String.

Comment: You can consider using this url as well http://localhost:8080/greeting?status=Soemthing&name=DoesntMatter

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass "status" as the parameter. Because "status" is the default keyword for org.springframework.http.HttpStatus .
Change its name as "status_value" or some other name. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Even though, it is an old post, I wanted to share my solution.

You don't actually need `ModelAndView mv` method parameter. Just remove it.

Return view name as string:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);

    return "greeting";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late now, but I think this will help.

```
public class MyHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter( MethodParameter parameter ) {
        return ModelAndView.class.equals( parameter.getParameterType() );
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument( MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, 
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory ) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
    
}
```