# Spring @RequestParam with a value/name of "status"

Tags: java, spring

I am running a Spring boot MVC application, in my controller I have a @RequestParamter with a value of "status". When I hit this method through a RequestMapping (eg http://localhost:8080/pathToMethod?status=someStatus&otherParam=aThing&status=anotherStatus)

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value ="pathToMethod")
public responseType methodName(
@RequestParam(value = "otherParam", required = false) List<String> param, 
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) List<String> status, 
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    //code here 
}
```

It fails with following error:

> Field error in object 'modelAndView' on field 'status': rejected value
>   [Soemthing]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.modelAndView.status,typeMismatch.status,typeMismatch.org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [modelAndView.status,status]; arguments []; default message
>   [status]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [org.springframework.http.HttpStatus] for property 'status'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [org.springframework.http.HttpStatus] for value 'Soemthing'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.Soemthing]

Is there any way to bypass Springs default handling of the "status" parameter so that it does not automatically try to convert it to a HttpResponse?

[Link to similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180582/cant-pass-status-as-httpparameter-to-spring-boot-mvc-application/50904209#50904209?newreg=7903147233e04fc1bcbade63c688f6f1)

Comment: Post at least a bit of your controller code

Comment: It shoud be String instead of <List>String.  i.e., code change  
public responseType methodName(@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) String status){
    //code here 
}

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are accepting request parameter as a List but passing only String.

Check the below possible reasons.

1.Remove `List<String>` and make it `String`

2.Use any other name for request parameter instead of `status` because `status` is the default keyword for `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`

Answer (score -1):

With Spring 4 and Java 8 it’s possible to have optional path variables with the usage of Optional.

Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/path", "/path/{status}")
public String getResource(@PathVariable Optional<String> status) {
  if (status.isPresent()) {
    return service.processResource(status.get());
  } else {
    return service.processResource();
  }
}
```